# How to change filename of csv file to yesterday's date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Currently I'm adding a feature on my python script that can rename the converted file with yesterday date format right now my script is working with current date  my plan is to adjust it to yesterday.

can someone help me what I need to modify with my script I already test some script but still not working :(

my current script (get current date)

```
df.to_csv (f"myfile{pd.datetime.datetime.now().date().strftime('%Y%m%d')}.csv")
```

Thank you in advance guys

Comment: That is a low quality close request. The issue is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract a day. Use the `datetime` module to make it a bit easier.

```
import datetime as dt
f"myfile{(dt.date.today()-dt.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d')}.csv"
```

You may want to use `dt.datetime.utcnow()`, depending on how you deal with time zones.

Comment: You do NOT want to use utcnow() if you're dealing with time zones, see [Stop using utcnow and utcfromtimestamp](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html).